# Why is the step to download the KinectSensor binaries needed?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are these not available as Debian packages?

I see a few Debian ros-indigo packages relating to kinect, but I'm not sure which ones are needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207203/why-is-the-step-to-download-the-kinectsensor-binaries-needed?/) by [James Puderer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22174/james-puderer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on which Kinect you have. Some of the newer Kinects need these different drivers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1